# How to create a function in R?

Tags: r, function

Instead of write the command one by one, such as :

```
data_101$new_column <- "a101" 
data_102$new_column <- "a102" 
data_103$new_column <- "a103" 
data_104$new_column <- "a104" 
data_105$new_column <- "a105"
...
data_150$new_column <- "a150"
```

How to write a function which can save the works? 
Here is my command (not sure correct or not because I am still new to R)

```
table_name <- "data_101"
for (i in 2:50) {
  temp <- paste("dat_10", i, sep = "")
  table_name<- c(table_name, temp)
}
```

But I don't know how to continue it already, I have tried my best...anyone can help me? Will be very appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ls` to get the objects and then `mget` to get data in a list. We can use `Map` to add a new column in each dataframe

```
d_names <- ls(pattern = 'data_\\d+')
total_data <- Map(cbind, mget(d_names), 
                  new_column = paste0("a", gsub("\\D", "", d_names)))
```

It is usually better to keep data in a list instead of creating lot of objects in the global environment but if you need them as separate dataframe you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(total_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Using a reproducible example :

```
data_101 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15)
data_102 <- data.frame(a = 6:10, b = 16:20)
d_names <- ls(pattern = 'data_\\d+')
Map(cbind, mget(d_names), new_column = paste0("a", gsub("\\D", "", d_names)))

#$data_101
#  a  b new_column
#1 1 11       a101
#2 2 12       a101
#3 3 13       a101
#4 4 14       a101
#5 5 15       a101

#$data_102
#   a  b new_column
#1  6 16       a102
#2  7 17       a102
#3  8 18       a102
#4  9 19       a102
#5 10 20       a102
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, after I execute the command of you suggested, why is it shows

Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

? Is there anything I missed? Much much appreciated

Comment: @Tzun that's strange, seems to work fine for me for the small example I created. Does the dataframe have the same name as you have it in your example here? Can you paste what is the output of `d_names` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data frame within a list, so you can run the for-loop like:

```
data <- list()
for (i in c(105,106,...,150)){
    data[[i]]$new_column <- paste0("a",i)
}
```